# Redirecting output of multiple bat files to one console window

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am running multiple microservices locally for development purposes. Currently I am doing it by a .bat script, where I am calling other .bat files, which are starting my services. It starts multiple console windows, and this is not handy to navigate between outputs.

The script which is starting services now looks like this:

```
start cmd /k call api_one.bat
start cmd /k call api_two.bat
...
```

In api_xxx.bat I am starting iisexpress with my api.

I am looking for a way to make it more comfortable. For example by redirecting all of the outputs to a single one, with for example a prefix to identify from which script output lines are from.

Comment: Have you tried to redirect output in file using >> ? e.g. : start cmd /k call api_one.bat >> "C:\output.txt"

Comment: I thought about it, with using powershell `Get-Content output.txt -Wait` but this won't give me a prefix to identify the lines source.

Comment: You can add separator test like "---------------" in files between two commands ...

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't clear. My services are running simultaneously.

Comment: Not following here [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.0) has `-RedirectStandardError` and `-RedirectStandardOutput` so you could capture the output there and write it out?

Comment: Yes, but this has the same problem - I won't be able to identify from which source the lines are.

Comment: Nothing in the I/O system of the OS will magically prefix writes with a process identifier or tag. You'll need a script that opens a child process with stdout and stderr redirected to a pipe and writes the output lines to the console with a given prefix. You can do this in a batch script with a `for /f` loop. Multiple batch scripts can be started simultaneous without opening a new console via `start /B`, but don't do this if the scripts need to read input from the console; in fact it's better to redirect stdin to NUL in this case. And don't use `cmd /k` to run the scripts. That will be a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, where I was calling a batch file from a batch file which started another batch file.. to complicated to explain but let me get you some code that helped me:

content from test.bat:

```
set logname=.\log.log

if exist %logname% ( type nul > %logname% 
)

echo Now starting example.bat>>%logname%

call C:\example.bat >>%logname%

echo finished example.bat>>%logname%
```

so now here is content of example.bat:

```
echo starting integrated commands

start /b cmd /k "C:\example2.bat"

[some code to check for a process that starts in example2.bat] 

echo finished integrated commands
```

and the content of example2.bat can be whatever you want and is also displayed in the logfile.

Note that my example2.bat has an exit at the end, because example.bat checks if example2.bat is running. only when it finishes it goes on with the script. For myself it worked out I got everything from all 3 scripts into one logfile.